# MERGE Issue In Bulk Insert Sproc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having an issue with my "Merging":
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once.

Can someone help me fix this, as I do not understand how to correct the issue:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Files].[ImportFiles]
AS
    -- Create a temporary table for the bulk import
    CREATE TABLE #TempImportFileTable(
        [fileID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [FileName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [FilePath] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [FullPath] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [FileSize] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [FileExtension] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [FileCreated] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [FileLastAccessed] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [FileModified] [nvarchar](max) NULL
     CONSTRAINT [PK_fileID1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [fileID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY];

    -- Import into the temp table
    BULK INSERT #TempImportFileTable FROM 'C:\Program Files\o7th FileSystem to DB\import.txt' 
    WITH(KEEPIDENTITY, FIELDTERMINATOR =',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');

    -- Delete the Duplicate entries
    DELETE FROM #TempImportFileTable WHERE fileID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(fileID) FROM #TempImportFileTable GROUP BY FullPath);


    -- Now Merge the 2 tables
    MERGE [Files].[File] AS TargetTable
    USING #TempImportFileTable AS SourceTable  
    ON (TargetTable.FullPath = SourceTable.FullPath)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET                                
        THEN INSERT (FileName, FilePath, FileSize, FileExtension, FileCreated, FileLastAccessed, FileModified)
        VALUES(SourceTable.FileName, SourceTable.FilePath, SourceTable.FileSize, SourceTable.FileExtension, SourceTable.FileCreated, SourceTable.FileLastAccessed, SourceTable.FileModified)
    WHEN MATCHED                                              
        THEN UPDATE SET
            TargetTable.FileName = SourceTable.FileName,
            TargetTable.FilePath = SourceTable.FilePath,
            TargetTable.FileSize = SourceTable.FileSize,
            TargetTable.FileExtension = SourceTable.FileExtension,
            TargetTable.FileCreated = SourceTable.FileCreated,
            TargetTable.FileLastAccessed = SourceTable.FileLastAccessed,
            TargetTable.FileModified = SourceTable.FileModified;
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no duplicates in your data file?

Comment: "The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once." What it means is that more than one row of #TempFileTable matched with one row of [Files].[File]. The Merge statement doesn't know which of these rows to use to update [Files].[File], so it returns an error.

You may try matching on something unique, not just FileName.


By they way, it looks like your fileName field is nullable. So I whould replace the matching condition with (ISNULL(TargetTable.FileName,'') = ISNULL(SourceTable.FileName,'')).

Comment: I need to be able to match on FileName to check if the file already exists in the table

Comment: b.t.w.   adding in the isnull stuff causes the query to completly fail stating invalid column ISNULL

Comment: Isn't the `MATCHED` `NOT MATCHED` supposed to see if the record already exists or not?

Comment: Yes, but the error says that there are at least two rows in the incoming table (#TempFileTable) that have the same FileName. The Merge Statement doesn't know which one should be used to update the [Files].[File] table.
Now that I think about it, did you check that the bulk insert works correctly? If you do a select * from #TempFileTable, or a select distinct FileName from #TempFileTable, does everything look alright?

Comment: Let me try matching by path then, there should not be any duplicate entries into #TempFileTable there for the path... FileName I can see... but not path

Comment: that seems to have worked, but now am getting worse issue (Timeout).   Seems the procedure itself is very long running.  Only a 1M CSV file that it's trying to import from though...  any clues how I can tweak this to better performa?

Comment: I spoke to soon.  After running the Sproc for 10 minutes it errored out with the original message.

Comment: I think what I need is a `FullPath` field, and compare on that.  Something that contains `FileName` and `FilePath`

Comment: If you have performance issues, try to run the bulk import without the merge, that way you can see which part of your process is slow. In my personal experience Merge can sometimes be much slower than an update + an insert + a delete. If you think the combination of FullPath and FileName will be unique, you can use this merging condition: ON (TargetTable.FileName = SourceTable.FileName AND TargetTable.FilePath = SourceTable.FilePath)

Comment: Yeah, running tests now.  The bulk insert is fine, executes pretty quickly.  The merge is taking forever    I am finding that there are indeed duplicate entries, and am trying to figure out how to remove them from the `#TempFileTable` prior to the Merge.  If you can tell me how to do that in an answer, you'll get the credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have duplicates in your #TempFileTable.

IF FileName + FilePath were enough to make a row unique, you could use this condition for your MERGE:

```
MERGE [Files].[File] AS TargetTable
    USING #TempFileTable AS SourceTable  
    ON ( 
        ISNULL(TargetTable.FileName,'') = ISNULL(SourceTable.FileName,'') 
        AND ISNULL(TargetTable.FileName,'') = ISNULL(SourceTable.FileName,'') 
    )
```

(I don't know why the ISNULL() function didn't work when you tried to call it earlier, but it should definitely work this way, and handle the issues that arise with null values.)

If you really have duplicate rows in your original file and you want to get rid of them, you may use this kind of code:

```
DELETE FROM #TempFileTable WHERE fileID IN (
    SELECT u.fileID FROM(
        select fileID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FileName, FilePath OVER fileID) as r_number 
        FROM #TempFileTable
    ) where u.r_number>1
)
```

It is ugly, but when several rows have the same FileName and same FilePath, it will remove the rows with the highest fileID and keep only one.

EDIT: About the performance issue, first try to look at the estimated execution plan and see if you can add indexes to your tables. You can also try to break the MERGE procedure into on INSERT and one UPDATE statement. MERGE should be better, but in some situations it is actually worse than separate statements.

Comment: Thanks for this, actually changed the code that builds the import.txt file to include the full file path and name, so only selecting on that should do the trick.  Also, I used `DELETE FROM #TempImportFileTable WHERE fileID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(fileID) FROM #TempImportFileTable GROUP BY FullPath);` in a test `select` scenario and it seemed to do the trick.  Any benefits of user your `DELETE` statement over mine?

Comment: No your DELETE statement is better. I've been using ROW_NUMBER() too much lately and I tend to forget it is not the best answer to every issue -_-.

Comment: still not working.   Even with mine, gets about 7 minutes into it and bombs with the same error?

Comment: Did you check if you have NULL values for FullPath? Could you re-post your query to see the changes?

Comment: aye, just editted the original question.  There are no nulls.  It's weird, I just truncated the target table, re-ran it, and re-ran it again, and the issue went away

Comment: I don't have an explanation for this. I hope you will manage to make it work with the full table. I'll look at this question again tomorrow to see how it went. Have a good evening!

Answer (score 0):

Merge statement has a limitation that it cannot update the same row more than once, or  update and delete the same row. So please make sure that you have distinct rows with filename in you source data. 
Also, while doing the update you don't have to update the filename column as its going to be same in both source and the target tables.

You may get a work around in this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976316